# Duda lógica con programación en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

estoy creando una pagina web y tengo una duda de como optimizar/programar algo en Javascript.

Necesito calcular la grasa corporal, dependiendo del sexo de la persona, la edad y los pliegues. El dato de entrada son los pliegues que es el dato que se muestra a la izquierda de la tabla en la imagen.

Lo empece a programar con switch/case para que si los pliegues eran 15mm y la edad entre 17-29 asignara el 4.8 a una variable.

Pero el cliente me comento que los pliegues pueden tomar valores diferentes a los que se encuentran en la tabla como 16, 22, 34, 43 y eso se calcula con una regla de 3 simple.

Por ejemplo:

Si los pliegues son 16 se multiplica por 4.8 y se divide entre 15.

Si los pliegues son 22 se multiplica por 8.1 y se divide entre 20.

Si los pliegues son 33 se multiplica por 12.9 y se divide entre 30.

Entonces opte por condiciones IF les muestro el código que tengo.

```
if (sexo == "Masculino")
{
    if ((edad > 16) && (edad < 30))
    {
        if (pliegues == 15)
        {
            var grasa = 4.8;
            document.getElementById('txtgrasaCorp').value = grasa;
        }

        else if((pliegues > 15) && (pliegues < 20))
        {
            var grasamod = (pliegues * 4.8) / 15;
            document.getElementById('txtgrasaCorp').value=grasamod;
        }
```

Pero si lo hago de esa forma serian demasiados ifs, entonces busco que alguien me ayude con una idea de como optimizar u otra forma de hacer esos calculos. Gracias!

[image: Tabla de porcentajes de grasa corporal]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Si no hay una forma matematica, esto seria ideal para meter en una base de datos.. y si no, no queda otra que meter toda esa tabla en un array, y buscar la posicion que necesitas.. y si esta entre medio de otras dos, hacer la cuenta.. pero no, no queda otra, alguien va a tener que cargar esa tabla en algun lado...

Comment: @gbianchi Como meteria la tabla en una base de datos o en un arreglo? Estoy algo confundido :(

Comment: `Pero si lo hago de esa forma serian demasiados ifs,` ¿Cuántos ifs son demasiados ifs?

Comment: No se a que te referis con como la meterias... no te queda otra que hacer eso.. o hacer 1000 if...

Comment: @ordago Osea puedo hacer los ifs pero no se si afecte en algo en el rendimiento de la pagina web, es a lo que me refería por eso busco una alternativa a los ifs.

Comment: Hombre, al rendimiento no afectaría mucho, un if es poco costoso computacionalmente, pero es verdad que si lo llenas de ifs el código va a ser un infierno de mantener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voy a tratar de responderte con lo que entiendo del problema, a lo mejor tendrás que hacer algún ajuste.

Una forma de hacer esto sin que sea un infierno:

Guarda los datos en un array de arrays, donde cada uno es una fila de datos. Esto lo puedes hacer escribiendo el array a machete en tu fichero JS, o puedes intentar crearlo a partir del resultado de una consulta en base de datos. Al final el resultado que tienes que tener sería algo así:

```
var datos = [
   ["4.8", "...", "...", "...", "10.5", "...", "...", "..."],       // fila 0
   ["8.1", "12.2", "12.2", "14.6", "14.1", "17.0", "19.5", "21.4"], // fila 1 
   // Resto de las filas
];
```

Ahora lo que necesitarías es una función que determine que fila tienes que obtener, y una función que determine que columna tienes que obtener.

Para las filas, depende del número de pliegues. Tienes que crear una función que si te pasan 15, devuelva la fila 0, si te pasan 20, la fila 1. Para eso, puedes dividir los pliegues entre 5 y restarle 3 al valor. Si te pasan otra cosa que no sean múltiplo de 5 puedes usar tu fórmula de regla de 3 que te han dicho.

```
15 pliegues -> (15 / 5) - 3 = 0 -> fila 0
20 pliegues -> (20 / 5) - 3 = 1 -> fila 1

function getFila(pliegues) {
  if (pliegues % 5 == 0) {
    // Divisible por 5, uso la tabla.
    return (pliegues / 5) - 3;
  } else {
     // No divisible, utilizo la regla de 3 del cliente.
     return reglaDeTres(pliegues);
  }
}
```

Para las columnas dependes del género de la persona y la edad. Aquí utilizar una fórmula matemática es un poco más complicado así que una opción sería hacer unos cuantos ifs para ver si está en el rango de la columna:

```
function getColumna(genero, edad) {
  if (genero == 'Masculino') {
     return getColumnaMasculino(edad);
  } else {
     return getColumnaFemenino(edad);
  }
}

function getColumnaMasculino(edad) {
   if (edad >= 50) {
      return 3;
   } else if (edad == 49) {
      return 2;
   } else if (edad >= 30 && edad <= 39) {
      return 1;
   } else if (edad >= 17 && edad <= 29) {
      return 0;
   } else {
      alert("Edad no está en la tabla");
   }
}

function getColumnaFemenino(edad) {
   if (edad >= 50) {
      return 7;
   } else if (edad >= 44 && edad <= 49) {
      return 6;
   } else if (edad >= 30 && edad <= 39) {
      return 5;
   } else if (edad >= 16 && edad >= 29) {
      return 4;
   } else {
      alert("Edad no está en la tabla");
   }
}
```

ahora para acceder solo tendrás que hacer esto:

```
var fila = getFila(pliegues);
var columna = getColumna(genero, edad);
var grasa = datos[fila][columna];
document.getElementById('txtgrasaCorp').value = grasa;
```

Espero que algo de esto te pueda servir de ayuda